# TaskQueue BulkAdd taking a relatively long time to complete

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I've been reviewing our costs on appengine using appstats and I've seen that I have quite a few situations where TaskQueue Adds are taking 100ms (or more) to complete. 
The documentation says they should [take around 5ms](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#adding_tasks_asynchronously)

I realise 100ms isn't *that* long, but when the whole requests takes 600ms then 100ms is quite a big chunk of time.

[image]

Some of these tasks are using task_names. Is that what's slowing it down?

Comment: I've got the same issue. :D